# What is difference between ClientID and document.getElementById()?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a asp.net text box and I get Id of text box using

```
var tbFilterValueClientID = "<%= tbFilterValue.ClientID %>";
```

But when I am using it so I do

```
var tbFilterValue = document.getElementById(tbFilterValueClientID);
```

After that I am able to perform and get value of it like:

```
var filterValue = tbFilterValue.value.toString().trim();
```

So can anyone explain why I need to

> document.getElementById

and Pass Id of control? Why can I not use

> tbFilterValueClientID

directly?

Answer (score 0):

clientid gives only client side id of that perticular control which have id tbFilterValue on server side 
and you can`t able to perform opertion on id as its only an attribute

you always perform any operation on control and when you call getelementbyid you will get the control(element )

Answer (score 0):

Please understand that document.getElementById requires an ID by which the js engine can find the dom object.

the ID which is passed for getElementById is a given unique identifier for a control.

Client ID is the ID generated for a control by a server side asp.net control, and now you pass this ID to getElementById to get the object.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are getting a STRING not OBJECT by using var "<%= tbFilterValue.ClientID %>"

If you want a value of a TextBox you need OBJECT not id of the Object.

To Get the OBJECT you'll need Client Id of that Object.

So that you've to get the Id first and then get the Object by that Id and in the last from that Object you can get the value of TextBox.

Client Id is different from Server Id because , there can be controls (nested) with same Server Id, but Client Id is always unique, So in the javascript you need a unique Id to get the control.

So there is no such difference between output of ClientId and document.getElementById except ClientId works at Server side and getElementById works at client side.

Answer (score 0):

The script will not work if it store it in a js file.

```
var divID = document.getElementById('<%= infoDiv.ClientID %>');
```

When this on an ASPX page, `<%= infoDiv.ClientID %>` will get converted to `'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_infoDiv'` on page render time.

Where as, `<%= infoDiv.ClientID %>` in a js file will always be `<%= infoDiv.ClientID %>` and will never get converted.

Therefore, if you wish to use `<%= infoDiv.ClientID %>`, your function have to be reside on ASPX page.